# ML predict more than one step

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series

This maybe a silly question, but I was curious if/how the code from [machinelearningmastery post](https://machinelearningmastery.com/xgboost-for-time-series-forecasting/) could be modified to predict more than "one-step"? (if possible)

I know this needs to be modified, but how?

```
# construct an input for a new preduction
row = values[-3:].flatten()
# make a one-step prediction
yhat = model.predict(asarray([row]))
```

This is the script from the blog post where Jason demonstrates how to predict:

```
# finalize model and make a prediction for monthly births with xgboost
from numpy import asarray
from pandas import read_csv
from pandas import DataFrame
from pandas import concat
from xgboost import XGBRegressor

# transform a time series dataset into a supervised learning dataset
def series_to_supervised(data, n_in=1, n_out=1, dropnan=True):
    n_vars = 1 if type(data) is list else data.shape[1]
    df = DataFrame(data)
    cols = list()
    # input sequence (t-n, ... t-1)
    for i in range(n_in, 0, -1):
        cols.append(df.shift(i))
    # forecast sequence (t, t+1, ... t+n)
    for i in range(0, n_out):
        cols.append(df.shift(-i))
    # put it all together
    agg = concat(cols, axis=1)
    # drop rows with NaN values
    if dropnan:
        agg.dropna(inplace=True)
    return agg.values

# load the dataset
series = read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbrownlee/Datasets/master/daily-total-female-births.csv', header=0, index_col=0)
values = series.values
# transform the time series data into supervised learning
train = series_to_supervised(values, n_in=3)
# split into input and output columns
trainX, trainy = train[:, :-1], train[:, -1]
# fit model
model = XGBRegressor(objective='reg:squarederror', n_estimators=1000)
model.fit(trainX, trainy)
# construct an input for a new preduction
row = values[-3:].flatten()
# make a one-step prediction
yhat = model.predict(asarray([row]))
print('Input: %s, Predicted: %.3f' % (row, yhat[0]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward.

Create new dataframe (shold match your featue set)

```python
newInput = [[55, 82, 83],[54,35,46],[27,48,39]]
df = pd.DataFrame(newInput, columns = ['f0', 'f1', 'f2'])
```

To learn more on various ways to create data frames, check [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/different-ways-to-create-pandas-dataframe/).

```
# If you wanna check how it looks
print(df)

   f0  f1  f2
0  55  82  83
1  54  35  46
2  27  48  39
```

Make a prediction on newly created data using trained model

```python
new_predictions = model.predict(df)

# Check how your predictions look
print('Input: %s, Predicted: %.3f' % (newInput[0], new_predictions[0]))
print('Input: %s, Predicted: %.3f' % (newInput[1], new_predictions[1]))
print('Input: %s, Predicted: %.3f' % (newInput[2], new_predictions[2]))

# Output
Input: [55, 82, 83], Predicted: 44.040
Input: [54, 35, 46], Predicted: 38.439
Input: [27, 48, 39], Predicted: 42.230
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the post.. would this work on a time series application? My real world dataset is electricity on 15 minute intervals and I'm trying to find a way to forecast a few hours out.

Comment: Is your solution one of these methods? Thanks for any tips with working with time series data. https://machinelearningmastery.com/multi-output-regression-models-with-python/

Comment: My answer was to python related question you asked. But looks like the real problem is building your machine learning problem and finding a way to build a suitable model. Information you have provided is not enough to conclude the solution your problem is classification or regression.